# Wants to format text in JTextArea

Tags: java, swing

I wants to set the different tab size in text area, line by line. Can anyone give me a solution for it. Is it possible? I wants, after the text typed on text area, when I press format button, wants to add a tab for every line.
line 1 - no tab
line 2 - 1 tab
line 3 - 2 tabs
line 4 - 3 tabs

Comment: "Give us the preciouses" No but seriously, could you be a little more descriptive? Post some code? What have you tried so far? etc.

Comment: I have no idea to do it. Anyway I wants to convert a text according to the coding standard. Such as when I press ctrl+k in stack overflow

Comment: @camickr don't worry, mine will be marked as the answer soon enough ;-P

Answer (score 3):

Did you read the API? The API has a methods that tell you:

1. How many lines are in the text area
2. The starting offset of each line.

I'll let you read the API to find the methods.

You would then create a loop and get the starting offset of each line. Then you use:

```
textArea.getDocument().insertString(...);
```

to insert the appropriate number of tabs "\t" for each line.

Comment: A text area doesn't support attributes, so you would just use `null`.

Answer (score 3):

I think default tab size/length is OS/system setting dependent. `\t` I believe does 4 spaces by default on windows....

As far as adding tabs after a new line -- you could do something like:

```
line.replace("\n", "\n\t");
```

or

```
line.replaceAll("\n", "\n\t");
```

depending on your use-case.

if you need to tab in each time a little further, try something like:

```
String tabSpacing = "\n\t";
for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    String line = lines[i].replace("\n",tabSpacing);
    tabSpacing += "\t";
}
```

It's worth mentioning that the newline character differs on some system environments. For example Windows uses crlf (carriage-return, line feed) while the *nix's use just lf (line feed).

So in java you will either use `\r\n` or just `\n` depending on the system environment. One way to get around this would be to call the system's property.

```
System.getProperty("line.separator");
```

this can be used in conjunction:

```
final String lineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
line.replace(lineSeparator, lineSeparator += "\t");
```

etc...

`UPDATE --` Based on a comment from the OP -- you may want to check this SO thread for how to format text into a Java Standard Formatting for Source Code: [Java library for code beautify/format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468122/java-library-for-code-beautify-format)

Comment: +1, doesn't do what the OP described (or maybe I don't understand the OPs description), but your suggestion is a much better requirement then what the OP asked for.

Answer (score 1):

Try using setLeftIndent and specify different styles per line:

http://goo.gl/nA7opA (setleftindent man page)

Styles example: http://goo.gl/8Yda5p